# LED strip appropriate for fiber-optic cables

Tags: led-strip, optical-fibre

A project will use 20 fiber optic side-glow cables, 3mm-thick, with one controllable LED each. A WS2812 LED strip or similar would be perfect for the ease of controlling the LEDs, however all that I've been able to find seem to be difficult to attach the fiber optic cables to. Using a "regular" diode, I could just attach it with heat-shrink tubing.

What would be a convenient solution to this problem?

Comment: How is the cable terminated on the light source side?

Comment: @nick it's these [solid core cables](https://m.aliexpress.com/item/32682383650.html), if that answers your question

Comment: found this .... http://electropark.pl/led-5mm/7435-dioda-led-5mm-rgb-adresowalna-ws2812-clear.html

Comment: Note they make addressable LEDs in a "traditional" form factor as well. PL9823?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look at the [WS2811](https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/datasheets/WS2811.pdf) device which allows you to drive 3 individual LEDs. This is essentially the data controller and LED driver chip that is used in the WS2812 without the LEDs.
You can then drive one light pipe with each of the channels and 7 chips would provide control on a single data channel.

Comment: Thank you. Working with 20 separate WS2811 seems like a lot of avoidable work, so I was hoping to find a better solution, e.g. a strip of them in another form than the usual.

Comment: @Anna You would only need 20 chips if the LED you want to use is an RGB LED.

Comment: solder the RGB LED directly to the WS2811, attach pigtails for power and data, then heat-shrink wrap the whole assembly